Understanding PyGithub's create_hook Method: Difference Between config['events'] and 'events' Argument
I'm using PyGithub to create webhooks programmatically in my Python project, and I'm a bit confused about the difference between config["events"] within the config dictionary and the "events" keyword argument in the create_hook method.
Example usage #1: events as part of the config dictionary,
config = {
    "url": "https://example.com/webhook_receiver",
    "content_type": "json",
    "secret": "your_webhook_secret",
    "events": ["push", "pull_request"]
}

webhook = repo.create_hook("web", config)

Example usage #2: events as a separate kwarg to the create_hook method
events = ["push", "pull_request"]

webhook = repo.create_hook("web", config, events=events)


In this example, the events keyword argument is passed directly to the create_hook method.
So, whats the difference between these two?
I can't find explanation for this in docs
